# This Overlay widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets

Tags: flutter

I have got follow app:

```
class MyAppState extends State<MyApp>
{
  TenderApiProvider _tenderApiProvider = TenderApiProvider();

  Future init() async {
     await _tenderApiProvider.getToken();  
  }
  MyAppState()
  {
    init();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(builder: (_) => _tenderApiProvider),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: "My App",
        routes: {
          '/': (context) => HomePage(),
          '/splash-screen': (context) => SplashScreen(),
          '/result_table': (context) => ResultDataTable(),
        }

      ),
    );
  }

}
```

I need to draw firstly `SplashScreen` current code show at start `HomePage`.

In splash-screen I need to switch to HomePage after all data loaded. Here it's code:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TenderApiProvider apiProv = Provider.of<TenderApiProvider>(context);
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: apiProv.resultController,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {   
        //...
        if(apiProv.apiKeyLoadingState ==  ApiKeyLoadingState.Done && apiProv.regionsLoadingState == RegionsLoadingState.Done)
        {
         Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/"); // Should it be placed in Build??
        }
        });
    }
```

Could you help me and show to to draw at app start `SplashScreen` and then switch from it to `HomePage`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You will need to wrap your `SplashScreen()` inside a `StatefulWidget` so you can fetch your data in `initState()`. It is important to wrap `fetch()` logic inside a `SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback()` to access the `BuildContext` inside `initState()`. Also, that way, you avoid conflicts with RenderObjects that get destoryed while they are actually build.

Following a complete minimal example.
EDIT: You cant use await in initState({}).

```
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Wrapper(),
    );
  }
}


class Wrapper extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WrapperState createState() => _WrapperState();
}

class _WrapperState extends State<Wrapper> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      _loadDataAndNavigate()
    });
  }

  _loadDataAndNavigate() async {
    // fetch data | await this.service.fetch(x,y)
    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SplashScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: https://imgur.com/L1qe5ma the source https://gist.github.com/bubnenkoff/6afc662c2ca17f1e0905f44b6bf18f82
Could you help me?

Comment: I need a progressbar.   Is there a library that includes one?  my existing progress bar is trying the overlay widget can not be marked.  OverlayEntry _createdProgressEntry(BuildContext context) =>
            OverlayEntry(
                builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                    Stack(
                        children: <Widget>[
..
                            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),

Answer (score 0):

i use splashScreen

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SplashHome(),
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        '/HomeScreen': (BuildContext context) => new ImageHome()
      },
    );
  }
}

class SplashHome extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _SplashHome();
  }
}

const timeout = const Duration(seconds: 2);

class _SplashHome extends State<SplashHome>{

  startTimeout() {
    return new Timer(timeout, handleTimeout);
  }
  void handleTimeout() {
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/HomeScreen');
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    startTimeout();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      color: Colors.lightBlue,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: import file 
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

Comment: could you explain what's wrong with my code? For example why you use `home` instead of `'/': (context) => HomePage(),`?

Comment: The `home` property is the initial Widget of your MaterialApp. You want to dynamically change this Widget with the Navigator(), but after the data is fetched.

Comment: Why in example use `pushReplacementNamed` ? Why to change default Home?

Comment: @rollcake I tried adopt your example, but it's not working without `timeout`. I am getting error: `This Overlay widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets`